# Getting Finished Running <myapp> on phone, but no app launches

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Using an iPhone 4 running ios6.1, and xcode 4.6.3, with valid provisioning profiles, the app will not launch. The status bar just says it finished. I have tried: It works in the simulator fine. The app is a Utility Application.
Rebooting (Everything)
Product -> Clean
Create new project, and move the code there.

The things is, I created a new project and just slapped a button on it, and it worked fine.

Found something new: I created a blank Utility Application and tried to run that on the phone, it did the same thing. Then I created a new blank application and tried to run it on the phone, it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing and empty black screen in the simulator than you should check your **rootViewController**.

Possibly you are using a navigation controller and the rootViewController is not set.
So the app is not aware that it should go to  a specific view controller that you want to.

Comment: Works in the simulator just fine

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other device without JB? I've told sometimes JB can do unpredictable things to you device, not launching app seems like it.

Comment: It's not JB, and never has been.

Comment: Sorry, I just find your app works well in simulator, so I think there's nothing wrong with your code and config, I'm using the same software package as you, only I'm using iPhone 4S, and it works fine for me. Can you find a 4S, or a 5, or a pad and run again?

Comment: If only I could magically have a newer phone... oh well, I will just wait till the next time I see my buddy, he has a newer one :)

Answer (score 0):

Awful number of times this happens with my Xcode4.6 and I resolved most of the times with below few checks.

- Do a quick check if your not compiling any static library by mistake.
- Reset and relaunch the simulator/Power off your device & restart.
- Still if this continues - Quit and relaunch the Xcode.

Comment: How do I check for the static library?

Comment: Have you added any additional targets as a static library in your application ? If No, You can skip step -1.

Comment: Try relaunching your Xcode(Probably should fix the issue) - if still the problem continues, reboot your device.

Comment: Already tried that, and rebooting the dev computer, but will try again.

Comment: I requested a reboot(Power on/off) on your testing device- iPhone/iPad

Comment: I did, but I will do it again :)

Comment: Make sure you have manually deleted the previously installed application on the device.

Comment: Nope, same thing still happens.

Comment: There was no previously installed application

Answer (score 0):

Happens most of the times if you already have an app on the device/simulator installed with the same app id (bundle id)

Comment: No other apps on the device